# What is the difference between CMSIS RTOS and Keil RTX?

Tags: arm, rtos, keil, cmsis

I have read the articles about them separately, but there are no information about the relation between them.

What I understood is that there is CMSIS RTOS that ARM created and Keil extended it to CMSIS RTOS RTX? If this assumption is not correct then what is the relation between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the CMSIS RTOS is just an API defined by ARM and not an actual real time operating system.

Keil has offered a variant of their RTX RTOS which is compatible with the CMSIS RTOS API. So you can use a firmware written against the CMSIS RTOS API directly on the Keil RTX.

Comment: After your answer I read [this](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/jp/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00105262.pdf) document (which mentions FreeRTOS with CMSIS RTOS) and that made sense. I think you are right.